# DIV centering, on top of fixed background

Tags: html, css

I'm sure i'm overlooking something simple but I am trying to center the content div on the page. The background image is 16x9 and I want it to stay put while the center content div slides up and down underneath the header div.

here is my html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
<div id="bod">
<div id="head">
toolbar
</div>
<div id="content">
Hello

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my css

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
body{
    background-image:url(images/1920w.png);
    background-size:100%;
    position:fixed;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:#E9C9A0;
    }

#bod{
    width:100%;
}

#head{
    position:fixed;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    width:62.5%;
}

#content{
    width:62.5%;
    height:100%;
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

fixed , absolute, float cannot center or align  on a page or an adjacent element , they are not in the natural flow of a document and they do not care about display.

but they can hold content, wich can flow inside.

```
#bod{
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
}

#head{
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    width:62.5%;
}
```

You where actually very close , #bod had to be fixed, so #head can fflow in it :)

Answer (score 0):

The body does not need `position: fixed`.

Once you remove this rule the div centers as expected, as shown in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S7Jhd/2/).

Comment: hoho , i red his CSS  too fast, I mistook it for a bg position

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dQP8x/)

If that is, I will explain you what I've done:

I used Flexible Box Model or Flexbox, **but be careful! It's a box model under revision.**

I venture to post the answer because of two things:

1. Although I used the deprecated properties I think the browsers (at least my browser; I use Chrome 27.0.1453.116 version) not works with the new
   properties.
2. I think that is good learn this specification because is a [Candidate Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/Consortium/Process/tr#RecsCR) like W3C said in the draft.

Well, now I'll explain you what I've did:

First, I changed a bit the css code for the following:

```
@charset"UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

body, div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body { height: 100%; }

body {
    background-image:url(images/1920w.png);
    background-size:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color:#E9C9A0;
}
#bod {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#head {
    background: navy;
    width:62.5%;
}
#content {
    background: #333;
    width:62.5%;
    height:100%;
}
```

I changed a little your CSS code because you use, for example, position: fixed; but you want to center the element. If you put that property, you won't able to centering the element because it's fixed. Besides, there was elements that had height and width established to 100%, but it's parent didn't have a size.

Then, I added the follow classes to your HTML code:

**p-flexbox** and **flex-vcc**

Where:

1. **p-flexbox** means *parent-flexbox*
2. **flex-vcc** means *flexbox-vertical-center-center*

Here's your HTML code:

```
<div id="bod" class="p-flexbox flex-vcc">
    <div id="head">toolbar</div>
    <div id="content">Hello</div>
</div>
```

For the last, I put these CSS rules:

```
.p-flexbox {
    /* Flexbox: Init setup */
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: box;
}
.flex-vcc {
    /* Flexbox: Principal setup */
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -moz-box-pack: center;
    box-pack: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -moz-box-align: center;
    box-align: center;
}
```

Cheers,
Leonardo